# Save list of objects to a separate table by using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have class with the list of objects as shown below.

```
public class Details
    {

        public string Reference { get; set; }

        public List<Hotel> HotelDetails { get; set; }
 }
```

I already created stored procedure to save the Details table values. and its working fine.Following is my stored procedure.

```
USE [UL_SLHEV]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_EVoucherDetails_Insert]    Script Date: 8/9/2017 11:20:31 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Details_Insert]
    @XRequestReference varchar(15),
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @RequestReference AS VARCHAR(15) = ISNULL(@XRequestReference,'')


    INSERT INTO Voucher(
    RequestReference,
    )

    VALUES(
    @RequestReference,
    )

END
```

In here I have to save the hotel details list in another table in the same save method and in the same stored procedure. Following is the C# code that I used to save the hotel details in table.

```
public EVoucherDetails SaveEVoucherDetails(EVoucherDetails detailsModel)
        {
            Func<SqlCommand, EVoucherDetails> injector = (cmd) =>
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@XRequestReference", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = detailsModel.RequestReference;

                var pList = new SqlParameter("@XHotelInfoDetails", SqlDbType.Structured);
                pList.TypeName = "dbo.HotelInfo";
                pList.Value = GetHotelList(detailsModel.HotelInfo, detailsModel.RequestReference);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(pList);

            };
            return _sqlHelper.SqlSpExecute("SP_Details_Insert", injector);
        }

 private List<SqlDataRecord> GetHotelList(List<HotelInfo> list, string RequestRef)
{
    List<SqlDataRecord> datatable = new List<SqlDataRecord>();

    SqlMetaData[] sqlMetaData = new SqlMetaData[11];
    sqlMetaData[0] = new SqlMetaData("HotelID", SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlMetaData[1] = new SqlMetaData("RequestReference", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
    sqlMetaData[2] = new SqlMetaData("FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    sqlMetaData[3] = new SqlMetaData("ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    sqlMetaData[4] = new SqlMetaData("Nights", SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlMetaData[5] = new SqlMetaData("MealPlan", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
    sqlMetaData[6] = new SqlMetaData("StarCategory", SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlMetaData[7] = new SqlMetaData("Status", SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlMetaData[8] = new SqlMetaData("LastUpdatedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    sqlMetaData[9] = new SqlMetaData("LastUpdatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    sqlMetaData[10] = new SqlMetaData("CreatedDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    sqlMetaData[10] = new SqlMetaData("CreatedUserId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);

    foreach (var info in list) {
        SqlDataRecord row = new SqlDataRecord(sqlMetaData);
        int? hotelId = GetHoteId(info.HotelName);
        row.SetValues(hotelId, RequestRef, info.FromDate, info.ToDate, info.Nights, info.MealPlan, info.StarCategory, info.Status, info.LastUpdatedBy, info.LastUpdatedDateTime, info.CreatedDateTime, info.CreatedUserId);
        datatable.Add(row);
    }

    return datatable;
}
```

I don' t know how to get hoteldetails by using same stored procedure above mentioned. Can anybody help with me this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to debug your project? Your SP is just inserting a record with only one `Field Name` with a maximum of `15 Character`.

Comment: yes. I am getting the correct values for my object. But I dont know how to insert the @XHotelInfoDetails to my stored procedure to save the data.

Comment: Create a separate SP to save a `Hotel` and use a loop to save each (in a transaction)

Answer (score 0):

When using a parameter in sql it looks like:

```
  exec SP_Details_Insert "InputValueHere"
```

You have a multiple fields at your:

```
 sqlMetaData[0] = new SqlMetaData("HotelID", SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlMetaData[1] = new SqlMetaData("RequestReference", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
    sqlMetaData[2] = new SqlMetaData("FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    sqlMetaData[3] = new SqlMetaData("ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    sqlMetaData[4] = new SqlMetaData("Nights", SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlMetaData[5] = new SqlMetaData("MealPlan", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
    sqlMetaData[6] = new SqlMetaData("StarCategory", SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlMetaData[7] = new SqlMetaData("Status", SqlDbType.Int);
    sqlMetaData[8] = new SqlMetaData("LastUpdatedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    sqlMetaData[9] = new SqlMetaData("LastUpdatedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    sqlMetaData[10] = new SqlMetaData("CreatedDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    sqlMetaData[10] = new SqlMetaData("CreatedUserId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
```

Now if you want to `Insert` all this record Your `Stored Procedure`  cannot handle this data because it uses only one parameter values which is `VALUES(
    @RequestReference,
    )`.

You need to have a multiple parameter at your SP too same as your data and loop your `data<List>` to insert it all one at a time.

Comment: I don't know how you construct this `_sqlHelper.SqlSpExecute`

Comment: Actually this is not what I am looking for. My stored procedure works fine. But I dont know how to add the list of objects to that one. Thats my issue

Comment: try to check this `_sqlHelper.SqlSpExecute` how your stored procedure looks like.